# Why does my phone know what to do with an apk from one url, but not another?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have an apk file that I uploaded to apkinstall.com, which then generates a qr code to the apk file.  When I scan that QR code on my phone, it downloads and then asks if I want to install the app.  However, when I upload that exact same apk to my own server, generate a QR code linking to it, and scan that QR with my phone, my phone will download the apk, and subsequently have no idea what to do with it.  Instead of asking if I want to install the apk, it asks me if I want to share it via a social app!

I don't understand why it is treating my apk completely differently when it comes from the server of apkinstall.com as opposed to my server.  Any ideas?

Comment: who knows? maybe it is downloadede as non-apk file, but as a file with different format. Basically phone doesn't know what to do with an APK url at all. It is just a regullar URL as for the phone. Also the phone has no QR scanner by default, so it matters, what app you use to scan QR code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want install apk after clicking (downloading) you need define MIME-Type on your web-server like mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive"

Comment: sorry, but not exactly sure what you mean.  Are you saying they are including the hash as a variable in the url embeded in the QR code? like www.urlToApk?hash=theMd5Hash?  I'm still not sure what I am supposed to do to make the apk work from my server.

Comment: If you want install apk after clicking (downloading) you need define MIME-Type on your web-server like mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive"

Comment: Setting the mime type worked! Thank you!  If you make "set the myme-type" as your answer, rather than a comment, I can mark it as the the correct answer.